# Transition in v-for with VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I can't achieve a fade-in fade-out with an image displayed in v-for with VueJS. I want to display image by image using next/prev button.

I read this in documentation :

> Vue provides a transition wrapper component, allowing you to add entering/leaving transitions for any element or component in the following contexts:
>
> - Conditional rendering (using v-if)
> - Conditional display (using v-show)
> - Dynamic components
> - Component root nodes

So I arrange my code to have a v-if in my v-for.

Here a piece of code :

```
<transition name="fade">
   <img id='pvw' v-for='day in days' :src='day.preview' v-if='day.current' title='Preview' />
</transition>
```

And a little bit of css :

```
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-active {
  opacity: 0
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/hfp78gfe/) is fiddle to see what I am trying to do.

Please help me to achieve this, not sure why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to use **TRANSITION GROUP**, not TRANSITION.

I would suggest to use something like: https://github.com/asika32764/vue2-animate
which is great package which allows you to use CSS animations from AnimateCSS in your Vue application.

For example, in your case you would use something like that:

```
<transition-group name="fadeLeft" tag="div" >
    <img v-for="day in days" :src='day.preview'  v-bind:key="day" v-if='day.current' title='Preview'>  
</transition-group>
```

Comment: Thx, I update what i've done and it works but notice that attribute of image have to be placed on img element, not on <transition>. I've already used transition-group but i had forgotten :key which seems important.

Thx for your fast answer !

Comment: Note that `v-for` and `v-if` on one element is bad practice and will prolly crash many of your elements. That being said, I haven't found a way to make `v-for` with `transitions` work, other than adding a `v-if` directive on the same element.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing `v-if="day.current"` so I doubt that's ever going `false` long enough for Vue to recognize it to do the transition. If you just add `:key="day.preview"` to your image tag you'd be good to go.

https://jsfiddle.net/hfp78gfe/1/

Comment: `:key="day"` is better way to be honest

Comment: Why? Wouldn't that trigger a transition when anything about `day` changes?

Comment: I believe this is one of those "almost" times. I'm just wondering why.